# What is the origin of "eyewash"?

Tags: etymology, slang

I was passing a sign today that said *Eyewash*, meaning a place where one could wash an eye that had some foreign matter in it; a common thing in laboratories and factories. But the first impression I gained was of *eyewash*, meaning something close to *poppycock* or *codswallop*.

This set me to wondering what the origin of this term was; Green's *Dictionary of Slang* doesn't even include this as a headword. This source [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eyewash) suggests it is the verbal equivalent of a wink; is that so? Does anyone know more about it?

**Edit** Sorry if this wasn't immediately apparent but it was the slang term I am most interested in.

Comment: My first impression of "eyewash" was a lotion, not a place to wash the eye. Or nonsense

Comment: Perhaps you were conflating it with _hogwash_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two meanings included in the Oxford English Dictionary for *eyewash* are:

> 1. A wash or lotion for the eye.
> 2. *colloq*. Something that is intended to obscure or conceal actual facts or motives; humbug, blarney; nonsense; something said or done merely for appearance or effect; spec. in Mil. slang = bull n.4 4.

The colloquial sense has written use dating from the 1800s:

> 1884    C. T. Buckland Sketch Social Life India ii. 45   Most officers of any tact understand the meaning of eye~wash.

The [Wordsworth Dictionary of Phrase](http://books.google.com/books?id=IgjAJazrBWwC&pg=PA410&dq=%22eye-wash%22+idiom&hl=en&ei=UoZmTuirIdTF0AHii7m0Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) gives some explanation of why *eyewash* also means to "obscure something", writing:

> [image]

So this "fulsome adulation" is figuratively putting a wash over someone's eyes. There are no clear references on where this "wash" came from. It could be from the first meaning of *eyewash*--if you are flattering someone, you are figuratively putting some type of wash in their eyes that prevents them from seeing your true intentions. It could also be from a meaning of "wash" as in a coat of paint (a *wash of watercolor*), so you are again obscuring someone's vision. I would guess that the slang sense was actually a figurative application of the first sense, however.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; it was the colloquial meaning I was most interested in.

Comment: @BrianHooper--I see, let me revise.

Comment: @simchona, or this wash could have been referring to the fact that everytime you blinked or winked, a film of liquid is spread over your eyeballs by your body

Comment: @Thursagen: That's another option. I didn't think of that. So it refers to the eywash-er, not the eyewash-ee.

Comment: Might it not be related to **hogwash**, which seems to have been used in the sense of *rubbish/nonsense* somewhat earlier than *eyewash*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Perhaps--I was unable to find a strict etymology for the term aside from the first written use.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised to learn that *"In a pig's eye"*, [My eye!](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/my-eye), etc., are also related. Even if not, they probably all managed to lend each other currency by association in the popular mind. Hopelessly archaic today, IMHO.